# query to imlement block list

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables a and b as follows to implement a simple block list where users can block other users.....

## Table A

+------------+--------------+------+

|    Name    | phone        |userid|

+------------+--------------+------+

| Mr Sasi    | 01225 708225 |    1 |

| Miss Brown | 01225 899360 |    2 |

| Mr Black   | 01380 724040 |    3 |

+------------+--------------+------+

## Table B

+------------+--------------+

| blockedbyid| blockedid    |

+------------+--------------+

|     1      |       2      |

|     2      |       3      |

|     1      |       3      |

+------------+--------------+

"blockedbyid" is id of user who has blocked the user in "blockedid".

I need to join the two tables and fetch all records from table A such that the result has all users who are not blocked by a particular user [ie blockedbyid='XXX'].. Can you guys give the SQL query so that i can fetch the records as a recordset??? I dont want to fetch two different rowsets and compare it in php....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Parameter :USERID

SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT blockedid FROM TABLEB WHERE blockedbyid = :USERID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join

SELECT u.* FROM TABLEB b, TABLEA u WHERE b.blockedbyid = 'XXX' AND b.blockedid = NULL

It may work like that, give it a try.

Roadie57 solutions seems better though.